# How to select the next text object?

Tags: cursor-movement, custom-text-object

How can I move to *the next* text object?

E.g. with cursor on the first `,` in

```
{}, {}, {}
  ^
```

then calling `va}` selects the middle `{}`. This is the behaviour I want to be able to achieve consistently, even in cases like this:

```
{{}, {}, {}}
   ^
```

This time, `va{` selects the entire line.

How can I always move to the *next* text object? I.e., the cursor should not end up in an earlier position in the file after.

Here are the results of successively moving to the "next" `a}` text object as I consider it:

```
{{}, {{}, {}}, {}}
^
{{}, {{}, {}}, {}}
 ^
{{}, {{}, {}}, {}}
     ^
{{}, {{}, {}}, {}}
      ^
{{}, {{}, {}}, {}}
          ^
{{}, {{}, {}}, {}}
               ^
```

And after that, there is no "next" `a}` text object.

This should work across lines too, just like default text objects do. E.g. with the cursor in the first line first column (on the `v`) here, pressing `vi{` selects the `{}` successfully.

```
vim stackexchange
text objects visual
mode {} movement
```

I hope the next-text-object movement will do the same.

Answer (score 2):

[Targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) provides the strangely named ["next and last pair"](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim#next-and-last-pair) custom text objects, which cover your notion of "next text object".

But there is no built-in normal mode "*to* next/previous text object" motion/command, so, unless you can put your hands on a plugin that explicitly provides it, you could probably try to work around that limitation by doing `van}<Esc>` (`an}` being provided by the aforementioned plugin).

Answer (score 1):

For this specific object, one of `f{va{` or `/{`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`va{` will do. (I'm actually a little surprised that the last example worked.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Module [mini.ai](https://github.com/echasnovski/mini.nvim/blob/main/readmes/mini-ai.md) from neovim plugin [mini.nvim](https://github.com/echasnovski/mini.nvim)

Default mappings are

```lua
-- Next/last variants (similar to targets.vim)
around_next = 'an',
inside_next = 'in',
around_last = 'al',
inside_last = 'il',

-- Move cursor to corresponding edge of `a` textobject
goto_left = 'g[',
goto_right = 'g]',
```

- select left (last) `val{` or `valb`
- select right (next) `van}` or `vanb`

As far as I have checked `g[b` and `g]b` do not work as you expect. Maybe check with the author of mini.ai if there is something what can be done.

Comment: Do you know how it works?